# Verilog: Given clock is 10ns, how long does it take to add 1 to 10 bit register?

Tags: verilog, fpga

Please see the following verilog code.  Clk is a 10ns clock.  Will setting TimerCounter_10ns <=0 interfere with the increment (i.e. TimerCounter_10ns = TimerCounter_10ns+1).  Are there any other issues?

Thanks,
Stephen

```
reg [9:0] TimerCounter_10ns;
always @(posedge CLK, negedge xRST) begin
    if (~xRST)  begin
        ...
    end else begin
        TimerCounter_10ns = TimerCounter_10ns+1;
        if (imerCounter_10ns >= SamplePeriod[9:0])
            TimerCounter_10ns <= 0;
            .....
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: @toolic Why is the blocking assignment an issue?

Comment: Because your simulation will only match the behaviour of the real hardware when you use a clock with non-blocking assignments. In other words: if you use blocking assignments your simulation will **not match** what the real hardware does.

Comment: @Oldfart  Doesn't each one work differently?  Wouldn't the if condition in my verilog code not execute until TimerCounter_10ns = TimerCounter_10ns + 1 completes?  If I change that to a non-blocking assignment, wouldn't the if condition execute at the same time as the increment by one statement?  If so and SamplePeriod[9:0] <= TImerCounter_10ns was true, the items in the if statement would execute.

Comment: is it supposed to be synthesized?

Comment: This is HDL, not some standard C-like programming language. If you want to synthesize you must follow the rules! I can write `a <= #6.125 b;` and it will simulate perfectly, but it will never work in hardware.  If you switch to non-blocking and then get behaviour you don't want, then your code is wrong and needs to be re-written.

Answer (score 2):

with some modifications , usually in fpga we wont use active low resets in the design as it will create more LUT usage and its not efficient way to implement it.So i modified the code to generate the [active high reset in the logic](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Adaptable-Advantage-Blog/Demystifying-Resets-Synchronous-Asynchronous-other-Design/bc-p/931744#M122)

```
reg [9:0] TimerCounter_10ns;
reg       sys_rst;

always @(posedge CLK, negedge xRST)
    if(~xRST) sys_rst <= #1 1'b1;
    else      sys_rst <= #1 1'b0;

always @(posedge CLK, posedge sys_rst) begin
    if (sys_rst)  begin
        //...
    end else begin
            TimerCounter_10ns <= #1 (TimerCounter_10ns >= SamplePeriod[9:0]) ? 10'h0 :
                                     TimerCounter_10ns + 1'b1;
            //.....
        end
    end
end
```

Added Non-Blocking Assignments in sequential logic with intra assignment delay(represents TCQ in flipflop on hardware) instead of using mixed blocking and non-blocking assignments(which is not preferred). It takes only 1 clk cycle to increment the counter by value of 1.if counter is initialized to zero, then it would take a maximum of 1024 cycles to reach the sample period count (10 bits , 2**10 =1024).